# In rspec-rails, How can I create a custom ordering so that I can run the specs according to my own order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to RSpec and I want to create a custom order for running the specs, I want the most important specs to run first and then the less important one's and so on till least important specs. Rspec already has the default global ordering as :defined, but I want to override this and create my own custom ordering. I have read a documentation (" 
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/overriding-global-ordering ") on this but couldn't understand how to achieve it. It would be grateful if you guys can post some example code with explanation.

Here's my spec_helper.rb file:-

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  #config.register_ordering :global do |examples|
  # model, other = examples.partition do |example|
  # example.metadata[:type] == :model
  # example.metadata[:type] == :controller
  # end
  #  model + other 
  # end
  config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
    arr = [RSpec::ExampleGroups::User]
    items.sort_by &arr.method(:index)
  end

 =begin
  config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
    items.sort_by do |group|
      case group.metadata[:type]
      when :feature then 3
      when :controller then 2
      when :model  then 1
      else 4
      end
    end
  end
 =end

config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
  expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
end

config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
  mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
end
```

And for example here's that spec file I want to execute first when the rspec is ran:- 
spec/models/user_spec_.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
require  'spec_helper'

describe User do
  describe 'must fill in user name' do
    it { expect(User.new(:name => "")).not_to be_valid }
  end

  describe "must fill in email" do
    it { expect(User.new(:email => "")).not_to be_valid }
  end
  describe "when email address is already taken, do not allow duplication" do
    it "should not allow duplication" do
      @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user12@example.com")
      # dup_user = @user.dup
      @user.save

      expect(@user.dup).not_to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get when I try to use this type of configuration with an array is:-

```
        /spec/spec_helper.rb:29:in `sort_by': comparison of Fixnum with nil 
        failed (ArgumentError)
       from C:/RoR/rspec_demo/spec/spec_helper.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in 
       <top (required)>'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/ordering.rb:151:in `block in register_ordering'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/ordering.rb:69:in `order'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/world.rb:34:in `ordered_example_groups'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
       from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
```

And If I use the following code for overriding:-

```
        config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
        items = [RSpec::ExampleGroups::User]
        #items.sort_by &arr.method(:index)
        end
```

Then the spec file runs bet the test doesn't pass returning the following error:-

```
      1) User must fill in user name
      Failure/Error: super

       NoMethodError:
       undefined method `inspect_output' for 
       RSpec::ExampleGroups::User:Class
       # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
       3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:732:in `method_missing'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:625:in `block in run_examples'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `map'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `run_examples'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `map'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1835:in `with_suite_hooks'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `run_specs'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-
      3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
      # C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
      #
      #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
      #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
      #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more 
          information.
       Failed examples:

        rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:9 # User must fill in user name
```

I have also read this discussion(" https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/547 ") about custom ordering but couldn't understand how to implement it.

How can I achieve the following? Or even If I have to only execute a single example from this file first like "should not allow duplication" first when I run the RSpec. How can I make it possible?

Comment: Curious what's the reasoning for that?

Comment: If I specify my specs this way, I think in future it would be helpful for me while running this specs. Just want to prioritize my test cases. How can I achieve it this way?

Answer (score 1):

To define a custom order, you just need to setup your own rules in configuration. As you want to specifically define important and non-important, you'll need to make your own list with the order you want and then sort the actual text list using it. Here is a crude working example that you put into `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
  config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
    arr = [RSpec::ExampleGroups::ImportantText, RSpec::ExampleGroups::NotImportant]
    items.sort_by &arr.method(:index)
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response, But I am kind of new to all this and still learning about it. So, For example, I have the following file containing in spec/features/log_in_spec.rb and more files with a different path that contains important examples or example groups. Where and how should I list them exactly as per this code?

Comment: No worries. This code goes into your spec_helper, located in spec/spec_helper.rb

Comment: Simple way for you to test this is to write this code block and put a breakpoint in it (byebug or pry). That way you could see how your specs looks like. But they should just be in this form, so I imagine your spec looking like RSpec::ExampleGroups::LogIn

Comment: The command prompt returns an error saying "/spec_helper.rb:30:in `sort_by': comparison of NilClass with 0 failed (ArgumentError)" where my line number 30 is 
config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
arr = [RSpec::ExampleGroups::User]
item.sort_by &arr.method(:index)
end
If I Just use the code as :-
config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
items = [RSpec::ExampleGroups::User]
end
@Maxim Fedotov

Comment: Without using the sort_by method and specifying the order in "items" itself makes the spec execute but fails it (even though it should pass), The reason for failure is given as "  1) User must fill in user name
     Failure/Error: super

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `inspect_output' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::User:Class "

Can you tell me what I should do now? @MaximFedotov

Comment: You mind joining the chat room? It'll be faster to grow through that way: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143680/create-a-custom-specs-ordering

Comment: All the test passes when I use the default configuration or If I use specific configurations as executing model specs first, then controller, etc. by just using  " metadata[:type]". I don't know why isn't it happening with this config.

Comment: No, I cannot use the chat room. It says I need to have 20 reputations. @MaximFedotov 
and I have used "items" only. I just made a typo here.

Comment: Alright. So to double check then:
You sure you didn't mistype your config. From what you've sent me, you got this:
config.register_ordering(:global) do |items| 
  arr = [RSpec::ExampleGroups::User] 
  item.sort_by &arr.method(:index) 
end
But there is a typo, ITEM.sort_by should be ITEMS.sort_by

Comment: @muneebzafer And yes, I am not quite sure why array doesn't set the right class, that's why I specifically use sort_by on existing array. I've confirmed it working locally. So double check you didn't have a typo

Comment: Yeah, I have used "items" only in the code, I just made a typo here.

Comment: Can you update your question with your spec configuration file? That'll be easier to debug that way

Comment: It'll also be useful if you could add that User spec you are using as well

Comment: Done @MaximFedotov

Comment: Thanks @muneebzafer. First of all can you delete that begin/end block. It might be messing with your config file.

Comment: Second of all, does your test actually run? I imagine so, but nevertheles, you don't have to include both rails_helper and spec_helper as usually rails_helper will include spec_helper

Also in case your spec doesn't run, Try defining it using RSpec.describe User do

Comment: Tried that too, Doesn't work. Yeah It shows that the spec runs but doesn't pass. But if I normally Run the test with :defined order then it passes.

Comment: Could you drop the error message to the question with my :global ordering. It's easier to read formatted, these comments are not great.

Comment: Done @MaximFedotov

Comment: @muneebzafer I've recreated my config to be same as yours, both with your case statement and without... but I still can't reproduce your error. As far as I can see, my approach works and there must be something in your codebase that's conflicting and ending up with an error. As I've said, just passing the array won't work, you have to use the sorting. I'd suggest to make a new project, check if the sorting works and then build up to your current progress until you find what change makes the config stop working

Comment: @muneebzafer I'd really appreciate if you could at least upvote/accept my answer. As I've said it's a working answer and I've tried my best to debug your particular example, but there is so much I can do over comments

Comment: I already upvoted, But it says to publicly display my upvote I need to have 15 reputations. @MaximFedotov and thanks for the help.